# BiometricPrompt as applocker

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new in Kotlin android.
I already have phone's applications list with checkbox for each in recyclerView.
but what i want is to make the user select any app that he wants to lock then the selected app will be locked using BiometricPrompt.
How can i use the BiometricPrompt as other apps locker and what service that track the user and lock the selected app when user open it ?